# Qt5: Xcb Xau symbols not resolved

Tags: linux, qt, centos, qt5

During installation of Qt5 with XCB support  ***./configure -prefix $PWD/qtbase -opensource -nomake tests -qpa xcb -qt-xcb*** fails because it isn't able to link to libXau and libXdmcp

```
/usr/local/lib/libxcb.a(xcb_auth.o): In function `get_authptr':
/users/salunkrj/libxcb-1.9/src/xcb_auth.c:163: undefined reference to `XauGetBestAuthByAddr'
/usr/local/lib/libxcb.a(xcb_auth.o): In function `_xcb_get_auth_info':
/users/salunkrj/libxcb-1.9/src/xcb_auth.c:377: undefined reference to `XauDisposeAuth'
/usr/local/lib/libxcb.a(xcb_auth.o): In function `compute_auth':
/users/salunkrj/libxcb-1.9/src/xcb_auth.c:256: undefined reference to `XdmcpWrap'
/usr/local/lib/libxcb.a(xcb_auth.o): In function `_xcb_get_auth_info':
/users/salunkrj/libxcb-1.9/src/xcb_auth.c:369: undefined reference to `XauDisposeAuth'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake: *** [xcb] Error 1
xcb disabled.
The test for linking against libxcb failed!
You might need to install dependency packages for libxcb.
```

libXau:
The symbol names for XauDisposeAuth and XauGetBestAuthByAddr do exist and show up when I do a lookup and **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** includes */usr/local/lib*

```
nm /usr/local/lib/libXau.a | grep "XauGetBestAuthByAddr\|XauDisposeAuth"
0000000000000000 T XauDisposeAuth
                 U XauDisposeAuth
                 U XauDisposeAuth
0000000000000030 T XauGetBestAuthByAddr
```

libXdmcp: There seems to be no symbols for the Xdmcp. 
nm libXdmcp.so | grep XdmcpWrap
nm: libXdmcp.so: no symbols

Is there anything specific that I need to mention when running configure to help resolve the libXau/libXdmcp symbols?

OS - CentOS5.6
Kernel - 2.6.18-238.9.1.el5-x86_64
Qt5.0.0 - opensource

Comment: Did you figure out how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to add -lXau to my makefile.  Under OpenBSD, not Linux.  I'm working on the same program under both in parallel, when I copied my latest over to OpenBSD I ran into this.

Xau is Xauth, I didn't intentionally use it.  Xau and xauth both have man pages, but they have more to do with authorization in connecting to the X server than what most people probably think about in terms of security.

At a configure stage you'd probably put an -lXau in your LDFLAGS.